# How do I solve the pre-receive hook declined error in Dokku deployment?

Tags: git, angular, docker, dokku

I'm currently in the middle of deploying an Angular4 application on a dokku instance, but, I keep on getting this error `! [remote rejected] develop -> master (pre-receive hook declined)`.

I'm deploying from a develop branch to master, so I run the deployment command as so `git push mediafactory develop:master`

I'm deploying via a Dockerfile, which looks like this;

```
FROM node:carbon

RUN mkdir -p  /opt/app
WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --save @angular/cli@1.3.0
RUN npm install --only=production

COPY .angular-cli.json .
COPY . .

RUN ng build --aot -prod

ENV APP_ID setYourAppId
ENV MASTER_KEY setYourMasterKey
ENV DATABASE_URI setMongoDBURI

EXPOSE 1337

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I tried running

```
sudo wget -O /etc/init/docker.conf https://raw.github.com/dotcloud/docker/master/contrib/init/upstart/docker.conf

sudo service docker restart
```

But, it doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally got the solution to the problem. I know someone may face the same problem as I had.

There are three main reasons as to why the above problem might come up.

First, If you land into this error,

```
remote: <app name> is currently being deployed. Exiting...
To <dokku remote>:<app name>
! [remote rejected] develop -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

You can easily solve the above problem by running these two commands from your dokku host.

```
$ sudo wget -O /etc/init/docker.conf https://raw.github.com/dotcloud/docker/master/contrib/init/upstart/docker.conf

$ sudo service docker restart
```

Secondly, as for my case, it was a problem with the permissions of the global node modules folder which would result into an infinite loop when you try to globally install the @angular/cli. Unfortunately even after providing permissions, the `pre-receive hook declined` error would persist. This was because of the @ngular/cli image I was using.

The error looked like this

```
...
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-
gyp/8.9.1
gyp WARN EACCES user "nobody" does not have permission to access the 
dev dir 
"/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-
gyp/8.9.1"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir 
"/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp"
...
```

You can solve the above error by adding the following line to your `Dockerfile`, if and only if the command `$ npm config get prefix` returns something like `/usr/local`, otherwise you may mess up your permissions.

```
RUN chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/lib/node_modules
```

Install the @angular/cli globally in your container with this command

```
RUN npm install -g --unsafe-perm @angular/cli
```

That's a work around that solves the problem.

The other problem that might cause the problem, is adding `package-lock.json` to your container. You might consider ignoring it too, for it may cause the same problem.
The new Dockerfile hence looks like this;

```
FROM node:carbon

RUN mkdir -p  /opt/app
WORKDIR /opt/app

RUN chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/lib/node_modules

RUN npm install -g --unsafe-perm @angular/cli

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install --only=production

COPY .angular-cli.json .
COPY . .

RUN ng build --aot -prod

ENV APP_ID setYourAppId
ENV MASTER_KEY setYourMasterKey
ENV DATABASE_URI setMongoDBURI

EXPOSE 1337

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Thirdly and lastly, if you are using a `Vagrant` dokku installation, the `pre-receive hook declined` error might be caused by low memory allocation to the virtual machine.

You may edit the `Vagrantfile` of your dokku repo and allocate more memory to your virtual machine. For example, you may increase the memory from 1GB to 2GB by adding the following line to your `Vagrantfile`;

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 2048]
end
```

Afterwards, you run `$ vangrant reload` to apply the changes you have specified in your Vagrant file.

If the problem still persists, and you are using `mongoDB`, you may want to checkout your mongo instances, and ensure that they are running as expected. You can check your mongo instances status by running `$ dokku mongo:list` on your dokku host.

Finally, If none of the above helps, and the problem still persists, you may have to destroy your dokku app and re-create a new one. TAKE EXTRA EXTRA CAUTION BEFORE DOING THIS!!!

[You may checkout a tutorial I wrote about deploying 2 apps in the same docker container, with dokku](https://medium.com/the-andela-way/deploy-an-angular4-app-parse-server-in-the-same-docker-container-with-dokku-5253f9d649c2)